# How to Mimic Bootstrap Dropdown's Auto-Close Behavior Using Vue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vuejs3

I try to drop the dependency of Bootstrap 5's javascript (while keep css style), and use Vue to manage all states.

It works quite smoothly when dealing with Modal.

However, when it comes to Dropdown, things get complicate.

Here is what I've done so far.

```js
// page.js
// And yes, I am using Global Build of Vue, for some reason

const vm = Vue.createApp({
  data() { return { ... } },
  ...
}).component('base-dropdown', {
  data() { return { show: false } },
  props: {
    variant: {
      default: 'btn-outline-secondary',
      type: String
    },
    text: String,
    placement: String,
    autoClose: {
      default: true,
      validator(value) {
        return [true, false, 'inside', 'outside'].indexOf(value) > -1
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    close(ev) {
      if (!this.show || !this.autoClose) {
        return
      }
      const rect = this.$refs.menu.getBoundingClientRect()
      if (this.autoClose === 'inside') {
        if (ev.clientX >= rect.left && ev.clientX <= rect.right
            && ev.clientY >= rect.top && ev.clientY <= rect.bottom) {
          this.show = false
          return
        }
      } else if (this.autoClose === 'outside') {
        if (ev.clientX < rect.left || ev.clientX > rect.right
            || ev.clientY < rect.top && ev.clientY > rect.bottom) {
          this.show = false
          return
        }
      } else {
        this.show = false
      }
    },
  },
  watch: {
    show(val) {
      if (val) {
        setTimeout(() => window.addEventListener('click', this.close))
      } else {
        window.removeEventListener('click', this.close)
      }
    },
  },
  template: '#base-dropdown',
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script src="/url/to/cdn/vue.global.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      ...
    </div>
    <template id="base-dropdown">
      <button type="button"
        class="btn dropdown-toggle"
        :class="[variant,text||'dropdown-toggle-split',show?'show':'']"
        @click="show=!show"
      >{{ text }}</button>
      <ul ref="menu"
        class="dropdown-menu"
        :class="[placement,show?'show':'']"
        :data-bs-popper="show?'static':false"
      ><slot></slot></ul>
    </template>
    <script src="/path/to/page.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Problem is: When I set autoClose to `inside`, which means the dropdown menu will only close if I click inside the menu (or the toggles button of course). However, the menu gets closed when it is scrolled behind some header, and I click that part of the header. I know it is because I compare pointer position against menu bounding rect to determine closeness, but the native Bootstrap Dropdown doesn't have such flaw.

I wonder how Bootstrap achieves the auto close behavior. Does it also add click event listener onto `window` and go through all the conditions?